# Greensock play() and reverse() on window.scroll and variable.onclick

Tags: jquery, gsap

These pages are quick-n-dirty-mock-up I am tasked with making to demo how the logo will animate.

1. Animation working: https://cbianchi.com/z/EM/logo-tween/box.html
2. Animation not working: This page should only play the logo animation if the user scrolls and then only reverse if the user hits back to the top button (fixed on the right at 800 down)
   https://cbianchi.com/z/EM/logo-tween/reverse.html

Code for the script and animation on the not working page =

```
<!-- load scripts after dom has been rendered -->
<script src="js/gsap/TweenLite.js"></script>
<script src="js/gsap/plugins/CSSPlugin.js"></script>
<script src="js/gsap/easing/EasePack.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- animation -->
<script>

var elkus = document.getElementById("elkus")
    anfredi = document.getElementById("anfredi")
    backtothetop = document.getElementById("backtothetop");

var elkustween = TweenLite.to(elkus, 0.8, {left:78, ease:Power1.easeInOut, paused:true});
var anfreditween = TweenLite.to(anfredi, 0.8, {right:130, ease:Power1.easeInOut,  paused:true});

$(window).scroll(function () {
elkustween.play();
anfreditween.play();
});

backtothetop.mouseclick(function () {
elkustween.reverse();
anfreditween.reverse();
});



</script>
```

Best! cbBKNY

Answer (score 0):

```js
var animationObj = document.getElementById("animationObj");
var animateObj = TweenLite.to(animationObj, 0.8, {marginLeft:"100%", ease:Power1.easeInOut, paused:true});
    
$('#forward').on("click", function(){animateObj.play()});
$('#backward').on("click", function(){animateObj.reverse()});
```

```css
#animationObj{
display:block;
width:50px;
height:50px;
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="forward" href="#">play forward</a>

<a id="backward" href="#">play backward</a>

<div id="animationObj"></div>
```

In your not working example, there was a jquery undefined error:

```
GET https://cbianchi.com/z/EM/logo-tween/js/jquery/jquery-1.10.1.min.js 404 ()
reverse.html:147 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at reverse.html:147
```

Also the click handler seems to not be working.

The reverse animation works if you do this:

```
backtothetop.onclick = function(e) {
        elkustween.reverse();
        anfreditween.reverse();
    };
```

or with jQuery .on("click", function(){});

Comment: OK - identified it's not the right funtion. mouseclick no, .click yes I think, so I have this code but the click does not play the animation in reverse- so close!  

    $(window).scroll(function () {
    elkustween.play();
    anfreditween.play();
    });

    backtothetop.click(function () {
    elkustween.reverse();
    anfreditween.reverse();
    });

Comment: Just added a working code snippet. It's not using scroll, but has the working reverse() on click